# How to use a GPIO driver to control pins from a different device's driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I am experimenting with linux device drivers. I'm attempting to build an OV2680 driver for my laptop, a Lenovo Miix 510. On that platform the sensor sits behind an INT3472 PMIC, and accessing the driver requires controlling the GPIO pins of the INT3472. The INT3472 has [a driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-tps68470.c#L119), and a corresponding [MFD Driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mfd/tps68470.c#L54) which didn't work out of the box but which I have altered to work (my laptop's ACPI tables don't define an I2cSerialBus2 for the INT3472, so I just had to add an `ic2_device_id` table and create the i2c device with `echo INT3472 0x48 | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-7/new_device` - this creates a `gpiochip1` with the 10 GPIO lanes defined in the GPIO driver, so it seems to be working.

I can set and get values for those pins in a terminal using the tools libgpiod provides. For example `sudo gpioset gpiochip1 1 1` sets lane 1 high.

My question is; what is the correct way to control the 10 GPIO pins provided by the INT3472 in *my camera driver*? I need, for example, to be able to pull a pin low/high to trigger the camera's software standby. I guess the obvious answer is "use libgpiod", but if that's the case, how do I identify the correct "gpiochipN" file in `/dev` to open, given there's two INT3470's plus the main gpiochip0 in my laptop.

Comment: This question is misguided. You messed up **provider** and **consumer** thingy. First part about PMIC being **consumer**, while second part of your question is discussing how to access PMIC GPIO which it **provides**. They are completely different GPIO chips!

Comment: @0andriy sorry; I'm confused. I thought the PMIC I'm interfacing with in the first snippet is the same TPS68470 that would be driven by the drivers you linked, and you were suggesting that I should use the API that the driver for that chip is providing rather than the hacky method. Did I get the wrong impression?

Comment: You put your `gpiod_get_index()` inside https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/mfd/tps68470.c#L54 `tps68470_probe()`. This is how to get this right. In some (rare or broken) cases it might be that current way is plausible.

Comment: @0andriy Thanks for your patience, I appreciate this a lot; reading tends to only get me so far! So trying this again; given the GPIOs defined in the DSDT are actually **consumed** by this device, what I'm actually doing by turning those on is turning the tps68470 itself on, rather than the ov2680? That does make a lot of sense, given the other i2c device that shows up when I do that is at 0x48 which is the first of the possible addresses for the tps68470. So I need to alter the `tps68470_probe()` function to get those GPIOs and turn them on when the function's called (i.e. at boot I think)

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm not familiar with the device. It would be nice if you can get schematics of something similar to see how actually this camera PMIC(s) is(are) connected to the SoC. And also datasheet for the PMIC may help a lot.

Comment: @0andriy PMIC datasheet here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps68470.pdf?ts=1597253028858&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS68470 - I'll look for a schematic. I'm also going through the atomisp-ov2680 driver to see how that handles things

Comment: @0andriy there's [another ov2680 driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/staging/media/atomisp/i2c/atomisp-ov2680.c#L1241) in existence for atomisp who's probe function is actually doing exactly this hack; it ends up calling [gmin_detect_pmic()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/staging/media/atomisp/pci/atomisp_gmin_platform.c#L503) which is using `acpi_dev_get_first_match_dev` and `bus_find_device_by_acpi_dev`. This won't work on my system, because the _UID param to `acpi_dev_get...` is null so it'll return the wrong INT3472. But, maybe fixable.

Comment: AtomISP v2 is quite bad example, don't take it into consideration (and actually it uses system PMIC, while in your case it is a dedicated one). In your case it's IPUv3.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/media/pci/intel

Comment: Okay, from pmic datasheet it seems that 3 GPIOs connected to IC_A, IC_B and #reset. If first two are high the pmic I2C address is 0x48. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: @0andriy yep, so that's what's happening here then. The ov2680 itself definitely does power on at the same time (or presumably, immediately afterwards) though too; it drops into i2cdetect and I can even talk to it over i2c and get the 0x2680 back as ID...I guess the PMIC's supplies to the sensor are on by default?

Comment: Without datasheet and schematics it's hard to say. Sensor may require more than one power rail and what you see it's just a proof that i2c part of the sensor is on. And PMICs usually have a firmwares that define flow (maybe this one is dumb and driver should take care of, I dunno).

Comment: @0andriy Yeah. I emailed Lenovo asking for a schematic, see what they say.  I got the MFD driver to load (no I2CSerialBus2 for the INT3472 so I had to stick in a table of `i2c_device_id`) and it creates a gpiochip1 with 10 lanes, which is great. I'm still unsure how to tell _that_ driver that I want to turn a particular lane on/off from _my_ driver though. The camera datasheet specifies the use of a GPIO pin which is probably provided by the PMIC to use as XSHUTDN for software standby, so ideally I need to do be able to do that. I edited the question to have more of that focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I came across the right way to do it [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/board.html#platform-data). In short, you can map the GPIO pins to the device like so in the camera driver (as a part of the `.probe` function):

```c
    static struct gpiod_lookup_table ov2680_gpios = {
        .dev_id = "i2c-OVTI2680:00",
        .table = {
            GPIO_LOOKUP_IDX("tps68470-gpio", 7, "s_enable", 0, GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH),
            GPIO_LOOKUP_IDX("tps68470-gpio", 8, "s_idle", 0, GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH),
            GPIO_LOOKUP_IDX("tps68470-gpio", 9, "s_resetn", 0, GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH),
            { },
        },
    };

    gpiod_add_lookup_table(&ov2680_gpios);
```

The `.dev_id` member matches the device name. `GPIO_LOOKUP_IDX` is a macro that takes the label of the GPIO chip (tps68470-gpio), the index of the pin in the chip (given by the PMIC's GPIO driver [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-tps68470.c#L119), plus a function name, index in the function and some flags. Once the lookup table is built it can be registered with `gpiod_add_lookup_table()`. Once that's done you can fetch the pins using `gpiod_get...`:

```c
/* ov2680 is a struct ov2680_device containing, amongst other things... */
struct ov2680_device {
    gpio_desc            *s_enable;
    struct i2c_device    *client;
}; 

ov2680->s_idle = gpiod_get_index(&ov2680->client->dev, "s_idle", 0, GPIOD_OUT_HIGH);
```

I *think* this is right; but I'm going to leave this open for a while in case a better answer comes along.

Comment: Yes, this is one way of how to create a **board file** to up-level the poorness of ACPI tables. I can't say this is ideal, but I can't say this is ugly either.

Comment: @0andriy thanks, it seems to be working. I also modifed the MFD driver's `.probe()` to turn on the pins it consumes like you suggested, and after patching in an I2CSerialBusV2 entry to the DSDT entry for the PMIC it's now probing automatically on boot which is nice. Really appreciate your help; on the back of your answers I also managed to get the regulator and clock drivers for the PMIC working too so that the camera driver can consume those resources, which feels like a good bit of progress.